# troubleshooting email forwards not being sent, but no error message

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, applications

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on this problem. My co-coworker has an ICS Android and is using the stock email app for our exchange server. When he forwards an email that has an attachment, it keeps getting stripped out. I'll give you some of the steps I've already gone through.

I can send attachments of various types through my phone, granted I'm on JB.
 --should rule out server/global issues
I tried sending different types of attachments, small and large from his phone.
 --not a file-type issue or file-size issue
I verified that the attachment showed on the email draft.

Now that I think about it, I didn't look at his sent. I'll check that tomorrow.

What am I missing here? I'm hoping this is a simple setting issue. Would it help if I tried to get a log? I'm not quite sure how to get the log for the email app.

Comment: It would for sure help to name the device, as "stock email app" != "stock email app" (different manufacturers use different apps).

Comment: I did not know that... is there an "about" somewhere where I can find the name and version?

I checked app manager, running, Email, the process is com.android.email 53MB

|| I also have com.android.exchange running